# Where can I find DSL definition for scmVersion in build.gradle file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am looking in to a build.gradle file and it has the below git configuration section. Trying to find definition of each parameter in it, but could not find on web. 
For instance it is not available in:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/

Where can I find this documentation.

```
scmVersion {
    repository {
        type = "git"
        directory = project.rootProject.file("./")
        remote = 'origin'
    }

    checks {
        uncommittedChanges = true
        aheadOfRemote = false
    }

    tag {
        prefix = 'xxx-client'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scmVersion` in your case is probably the [axion-release-plugin](https://github.com/allegro/axion-release-plugin). You didn't provide the full gradle build script content, but it could contain somthing like:

```
plugins {
  id 'pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release' version '1.3.2'
}
```

That means, that in some cases, you will not find a DSL definition on official Gradle sources, you need to look up a plugin documentation in that case. Here is the [documentation](http://axion-release-plugin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and help